# how to post and get the values from two table is in yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

i Post values from single and get from table it is working fine. if post from two table and get from two table is not showing second table data. i called var_dump($aaa). but it showing string "",

i show here my controller code here. please suggest how cloud be change :

i did like this. output showing like string(0) ""

```
 $model=new Recipe;   $model1= new Ingredienttype;
if(isset($_POST['Recipe']))
{
$model->attributes=$_POST['Recipe'];
 $recipe_name=$model->name;
 $course=$model->course_id;
$cuisine=$model->cuisinename;
 $type=$model->type;
 $calorie=$model->calorie_count;
 if(isset($_POST['Ingredienttype']))
$model1->attributes=$_POST['Ingredienttype'];
$ingredient=$model1->ingredient_type;
 var_dump($ingredient);
{

$this->redirect(array('advancesearch1','name'=>$recipe_name,
    'course'=>$course,'cuisine'=>$cuisine,'ingredient'=>$ingredient,
         'type'=>$type,'calorie'=>$calorie
        ));
    }
```

}

```
  $this->render('newadv',array('model'=>$model,'model1'=>$model1));
```

}

```
public function actionAdvancesearch1()
    {
       $model=new Recipe;

       $name=$_GET['name'];
       $course1=$_GET['course'];
       $cuisine1=$_GET['cuisine'];
       $type1=$_GET['type'];
       $calorie1=$_GET['calorie'];
       $ingredient1=$_GET['ingredient'];
       var_dump($ingredient1);
```

Comment: post complete controll function?

Comment: i posted complete function

Comment: in the starting of if try to print the POST like this,`print_r($_POST);` then you can see what values you getting

Comment: and why this `{` after vardump?

Comment: i removed that { brace also then also am getting   string(0) ""

Comment: try print_r($_POST); you'll get a clear idea

Comment: same repeating ie string(0) ""

Comment: ingrident table is foreignkey relationship

Comment: actually i want to  do advance search. its working fine. when searching from the single table its working. when i searching for another table its not working ie second table values showing like string(0) ""

Comment: print_r($_POST) wont output as string(0),it means you var_dump is executing. put this print_r($_POST) in starting line of `if(isset($_POST['Recipe']))
{  // here`

Comment: not taking??? what do you mean bro.. put exit after it and check

Answer (score 1):

Check next:

1. var_dump($_POST['Ingredienttype'])
2. ingredient_type is safe attribute

Comment: when given above code . i am getting this error object(Ingredient)#86 (12) { ["_md":"CActiveRecord":private]=> object(CActiveRecordMetaData)#88 (5) { ["tableSchema"]=> object(CMysqlTableSchema)#89 (9) { ["schemaName"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(10) "ingredient" ["rawName"]=> string(12) "`ingredient`"

Comment: `i am getting this error object(Ingredient)#86 (12) { `  this is just magnificent